# SFMC Cloud page : Update Salesforce field when form Submitted

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I want to update a consent field in a SalesCloud Account when the cloud page form button "Valider votre désabonnement" is clicked. Indeed, I would like to retrieve the Account Id to be able to update the field "AbonneNewsletter__pc" as  false when submitting the form.

The fields on my data extension named :
"PersonContactId" for the Person Contact ID of the account and the "Id" for the Account ID.
I had created this code in my cloud page but nothing happened when I test the cloud page. I do not even have the message error displaying. I think something is wrong with my HTML or the ID I want to retrieve.
Here is the code  I have created :

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
try{
</script>   
%%[
//Variable declaration and Initialization//
var @PersonAccountId, @AbonneNewsletter, @subscriberRows, @subscriberRow, @UpdateAccount, @ContactId

IF RequestParameter("submitted") == 'true' then

set @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
     "Account",
     "AbonneNewsletter__pc",
     "PersonContactId", "=", @ContactId)

IF RowCount(@subscriberRows) >= 1 THEN

  set @subscriberRow = Row(@subscriberRows, 1)
  set @PersonAccountId = Field(@subscriberRow, "Id")
  set @ContactId = Field(@subscriberRow, "PersonContactId")
  set @UpdateAccount = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
      'Account', @PersonAccountId,
      'AbonneNewsletter__pc', "false")

endif
endif
]%%

 

<script runat="server">
}catch(e){
Write(Stringify(e));
}
</script>

 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

      %%[ if @UpdateAccount == 1 then ]%%
<p>Votre préférence a été prise en compte</p>
      %%[ elseif @UpdateAccount == 0 then ]%%
<p>La mise à jour de vos préférences a échoué</p>
      %%[ endif ]%%
<h2> V15 Mettre à jour  vos préférences de communications</h2>
<form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
<label>Je me désabonne de la newsletter</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="AbonneNewsletter" value="%%=v(@AbonneNewsletter)=%%">
<input id="submitted" type="hidden" name="submitted" value="submitted">
<input type="submit" value="Valider votre désabonnement">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty the reason is that the variable @ContactId is empty so the RetrieveSalesforceObjects() function will never return any record.

In the example below i assume that you are using ContactId or LeadId as the marketing cloud subscriberKey. (PersonAccounts is also using PersonContactId).

Marketing Cloud pages will then have access to this key using the following line. The subscriberKey will also be added if link is clicked from an email footer using the CloudPageURL() function.

`SET @ContactId = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")`

**Example in code:**

```html
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
try{
</script>   
%%[
//Variable declaration and Initialization//
var @PersonAccountId, @AbonneNewsletter, @subscriberRows, @subscriberRow, @UpdateAccount, @ContactId, @subId

// GET the Marketing Cloud Key. Here assumed that this is Contact or LeadId
SET @subId = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")
// SET @subId = '' // Manually set the contactId when debugging. 

/*
* This below IF block is added as a bonus and has nothing todo with issue.
* @example https://example.com?s=MDAzMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAw
* @ampscript example: %%=CloudPageURL(123, 's', Base64Encode('003***************'))=%%
**/
IF EMPTY(@subid) THEN
      SET @subId = QueryParameter('s')
      SET @subId = Base64Decode(@subId)
      IF EMPTY(@subid) THEN
            SET @error = 1
      ENDIF
ENDIF


IF RequestParameter("submitted") == 'true' then

SET @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
     "Account",
     "AbonneNewsletter__pc",
     "PersonContactId", "=", @subId)

      IF RowCount(@subscriberRows) >= 1 THEN

      SET @subscriberRow = Row(@subscriberRows, 1)
      SET @PersonAccountId = Field(@subscriberRow, "Id")
      SET @ContactId = Field(@subscriberRow, "PersonContactId")
      SET @UpdateAccount = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
            'Account', @PersonAccountId,
            'AbonneNewsletter__pc', "false")

      ENDIF
ENDIF
]%%

 

<script runat="server">
}catch(e){
Write(Stringify(e));
}
</script>

 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

      %%[ if @UpdateAccount == 1 then ]%%
<p>Votre préférence a été prise en compte</p>
      %%[ elseif @UpdateAccount == 0 then ]%%
<p>La mise à jour de vos préférences a échoué</p>
      %%[ endif ]%%
<h2> V15 Mettre à jour  vos préférences de communications</h2>
<form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
<label>Je me désabonne de la newsletter</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="AbonneNewsletter" value="%%=v(@AbonneNewsletter)=%%">
<input id="submitted" type="hidden" name="submitted" value="submitted">
<input type="submit" value="Valider votre désabonnement">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Tip 1:

You can make a cloud page that can handle LeadId and ContactIds

```html
/* Check for subscriberKey or set error to stop the rest of the code */
SET @error = 0
set @subId = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")
IF EMPTY(@subid) THEN
      SET @subId = QueryParameter('s')
      SET @subId = Base64Decode(@subId)
      IF EMPTY(@subid) THEN
      SET @error = 1
      ENDIF
ENDIF

/* Continue if we got a subscriberKey*/
IF @error == 0 THEN
      IF IndexOf(@subid,"003") == 1 THEN
            SET @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
                                    "Contact",
                                    "AbonneNewsletter__c",
                                    "Id", "=", @subId)
      ELSEIF IndexOf(@subid,"00Q") == 1 THEN
           SET @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
                                    "Lead",
                                    "AbonneNewsletter__c",
                                    "Id", "=", @subId)
      ELSE
            SET @error = 1
      ENDIF
ENDIF
```

Tip 2:
Setting the checkbox input values.
See documentation here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp

```html
%%[
/* Continues here with code from tip 1 */

/* Update Salesforce if submitted */
IF @error == 0 AND RequestParameter("submitted") == "true" THEN
      /* Your update code */
ELSE
      SET @error = 1
ENDIF


/* Set any personal details or checkbox values */
IF @error == 0 THEN
      SET @rowCount = RowCount(@subscriberRows)
      IF @rowCount == 1 THEN
            SET @subscriberRow = ROW(@subscriberRows, 1)
            SET @isNewsletter = FIELD(@subscriberRow, "AbonneNewsletter__c")
            /* We set the checkbox value to checked so it is visibly checked in HTML form */
            SET @checkboxNewsletter = Iif(@isNewsletter == true, "checked", "")
      ELSE
            SET @error = 1
      ENDIF
ENDIF
]%%

<form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
<!-- @checkboxNewsletter is added to the input element as an attribute without value. 
If the value is set to empty then the attribute will result in an unchecked input field -->
<input type="checkbox" name="AbonneNewsletter" 
       value="%%=v(@isNewsletter)=%%" %%=v(@checkboxNewsletter)=%%>
<input id="submitted" type="hidden" name="submitted" value="submitted">
<input type="submit" value="Valider votre désabonnement">
</form>
```